# Best way to integrate different variables into one pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, ldap, databricks

I am collecting data from 3 different sources; LDAP 1, LDAP 2 and Databricks sql.  The LDAP results are json dicts and the sql is an narray inside a series.  I have been using a very non-pythonic way doing string concatenation field by field to generate a csv, but this seems dirty.   Is there a better approach, even when some fields may not exist? Can I check and resolve missing data before bringing the strings together or loading into a df?

```
result = result + "\"" + json[fieldn] + "\"" if json[fieldn] else result + "\"na"\""
```